# Extending React Stateful Function Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

because of the release of the React Hooks, I wanted to try to "update" one or two React Component into the new Stateful Function Component using Hooks.

So, I wanted to update my "GenerciTooltip" Component, let me explain: right now, this is the `GenericComponent` → `class GenericTooltip<T> extends React.Component<T, {}>`. This is built this way because it takes care only of position the Tooltip centered with regards to its content, and to add a little arrow at the bottom of the tooltip (in fact, in this `GenericTooltip<T>` Component it's been implemented only the `componentDidUpdate()` method and it's defined the `tooltipRef` variable.

Then, for each type of chart I'm implementing, I'm creating a specific Component, and that's because different chart may want to display different data inside the Tooltip. So, let's take in example a PieChart: I've wrote the `PieChartTooltip` Component, which is the following one → `class PieChartTooltip extends GenericTooltip<IPieChartTooltipProps>`. As you can see, each specific Tooltip Component extends the `GenericTooltip` Component. In these specific Tooltip Components I've implemented just the `render()` method.

So, in the end, while the `GenericTooltip` Component takes care of improving the position of the Tooltip, the Specific Tooltip Component takes care of rendering what's right for the Chart.

Now.. I'd like to convert the `GenericTooltip` Component and the specific tooltip Component using the new Hooks, but.. Is it possible to achieve something like this? I mean, I cannot use `extends` keyword anymore.

Thank

EDIT: There it is the codesandbox → https://codesandbox.io/s/p54wor9k5j It's a simplified version of my code, but it shows all that is needed to my question (the real implementation of the methods are not really important, I think)

Comment: Would it be possible for you to put your code into a basic [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io) so that others can see more clearly what you are trying to do? Then, for those who can offer help, they can fork your sandbox and offer suggestions for code modifications that will help you to convert your component into one that uses React Hooks.

Comment: Yeah, I can try.. I can't post the code itself because of copyright, in fact I tried to explain at my best, but I can make a simplified example.. Give me few minutes and I'll add a link

Comment: Thanks. I think that will significantly improve everybody's ability to help you more effectively. 

Comment: Even before hooks, it was never recommended to use inheritance for React components. I recommend first reworking the classes to use composition instead of inheritance and then it will be easy to convert the classes to function components. https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html